# How to align a inner DIV in the center of the outer DIV

Tags: html, css, margin, alignment

I have a bottom toolbar like this:

```
<div style="float:left;width:100%;position:fixed;z-index:210;bottom:5px;">

    <div style="float:left;width:928px;border:1px solid #000;background:url('/images/noise-bg.jpg') repeat-x;height:26px;padding:5px;">
         Toolbar Content
     <div>

</div>
```

But this toolbar is aligned on left side of the page. I want this DIV to be in the center of the page. Means same space area on the both side(left and right) of the toolbar. I can't fix the width of the toolbar, it is always `100%`. I tried by setting fixed `margin-left` but it is different on different browsers/resolutions and iPad.
Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: to make any content in center of a parent container we use this css `margin: 0 auto;` Try this in your class hope it works it is a repeated question.. you need to apply this to the content inside your parent div.

Comment: I tried `<div style="float:left;width:100%;position:fixed;z-index:210;bottom:5px;margin: 0 auto;">` but still on left side.

Comment: Edited: Please see the question again. Inner Div is toolbar to be aligned center.

Comment: cool now give `margin:0 auto` to your inner div

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your div has `width:100%` and `float:left`, so it will be the same size of your page and you won't be able to center.

Set your width properly, remove that float and apply a `margin: 0 auto` rule on your div to center it.

I made a jsbin to show that working:

http://jsbin.com/obepad/2/edit

Comment: No, it does not cover the width of the page. May be it is in another `DIV`.

Comment: actually I missed some code. Please see edited question. I have inner Div for toolbar.

Answer (score 5):

See my [working demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyTXW/)

the key thing is that you should remove float: left; from the second div and add margin: 0 auto;. If you can't do this please let me know

Answer (score 3):

Editted based on your edited question:

Remove float: left and add margin: 0 auto to align the border box. text-align: center will align the text. You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wFZNv/

This is the code:

```
<div style="float:left;width:100%;position:fixed;z-index:210;bottom:5px;">
<div style="width:928px;border:1px solid #000;background:url('/images/noise-bg.jpg') repeat-x;height:26px;padding:5px;-webkit-border-radius: 3px;-moz-border-radius: 3px;border-radius: 3px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
     Content
 <div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For your scenario, try:

```
<div style="width:100%;position:fixed;z-index:210;margin: 0 auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove float for inner div. No mater how you position your div, float : left will put in to the left margin. use margin:auto to center your inner div